# How to custom design the scroll view with a tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

I want to make A,B,C touchable buttons, but I also want the user to able to scroll between the related three `tableView`s.

`ScrollView` only has three simple dots to show the current view, and I'm not able to touch them. Is there a way that I can design something like the image below?

[image]

Comment: Your need is `Swipe View`, google it.

Comment: use three button A,B,C  and on click of button just change the content offset of scroll view y = 0 And x = value according to the view you will get your result and don't embed your button in scrollView

Comment: Should I show u a demo Code ? I need to build it in Swift I am having in Obj - c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is demo Code in Swift which you can use I Made a basic Code and you can modify it as per Your Requirement use table or collection in View as you require

here is my storyBoard Look

[image]

Constraint for scrollView ContentView [Must]

[image]

Here are outlets and code Required

[image]

and my simulator output is here

[image]

secondView

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the constraint of view1 and view2 inside ContentView?